# Suppose $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is (Lebesgue) measurable and $X \subseteq Y$ with $\lambda^*(Y \setminus X)=0$. Then is $X$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is (Lebesgue) measurable and $X \subseteq Y$ with $\lambda^*(Y \setminus X)=0$. Then is $X$ measurable?

I believe that $X$ is measurable, but I'm unsure whether or not my proof is correct:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. I show that $\lambda^*(A\cap X)+\lambda^*(A \setminus X) \leq \lambda^*(A)$.

\begin{align}
 \lambda^*(A\cap X)+\lambda^*(A \setminus X) & =  \lambda^*(A\cap X) + \lambda^*\Big((A\setminus X) \cap Y \Big) + \lambda^*\Big((A \setminus X)\setminus Y \Big)\\
&= \lambda^*(A\cap X)+\underbrace{\lambda^*\Big(A \cap (Y\setminus X) \Big)}_0+ \lambda^*(A\setminus Y)\\
&= \lambda^*(A\cap X) + \lambda^*(A\setminus Y)\\
&= \lambda^*(A\cap X) +\lambda^*(A)-\lambda^*(A\cap Y)\\
& =\lambda^*(A)+ \underbrace{\lambda^*(A\cap X) -\lambda^*(A\cap Y)}_{\leq \ 0 \text{ since } A\cap X \ \subseteq \ A \cap Y}\\
&\leq \lambda^*(A)
\end{align}
Since $A$ was an arbitrary set, it follows that $X$ is measurable.

Have I gone wrong here anywhere?

Comment: Looks good to me, just one minor detail: If $\lambda^*(A) = \infty$ then the inequality is automatically true, so you can presume $\lambda^*(A) < \infty$, which is necessary in the following steps to ensure the subtraction is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $m^*(Y \setminus X) = 0$, we see that $Y \setminus X$ is a subset of a set of measure zero hence since the Lebesgue measure is complete, we see that $Y \setminus X$ is measurable and has measure zero. Since $X=Y \setminus ( Y \setminus X )$, we see that $X$ is measurable.